# How to achieve this gradient painting?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, gradient

[image]

Hi all, this is a piece by Yute Sato (if I am not mistaken). I am curious how this very specific gradient was made, it seems like it was a Ctrl-D duplication on some gradient (mesh?) on Illustrator. Though as you can see, on the bottom half some of these looked dragged and painted over, with the gradient duplicated and static. I think this is an interesting result and was wondering about how to approach it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's less complicated than you think.

Just make some gradient. Here I've made a quick copy of the gradient used in your example.

[image]

Then use that same gradient for a bunch of fills and/or brush strokes. Maybe use *Blend Tool* to make some of those repeated patterns. Maybe rotate the gradient in some of the shapes like in the example.

[image]

This was made without much effort. To make something great it of course requires more work.

Comment: very nicely done answer... just want to add in using the blob brush for some of the larger shapes and the gradient tool to change direction, and to compress or expand the gradient in the shapes.

Comment: @Kyle, yeah *Blob Brush Tool* would probably be good to use. I just wanted to show that if you apply the same gradient to everything, you will get the wanted effect. Doesn't matter much exactly what you draw.

Comment: Oh wow I didnt expect the blob to end up like that! thank you loads✨